# Sentry database model usage example

Tags: cloudera, hortonworks-data-platform, mapr, apache-sentry

Sentry has two models.one is file based model and second is database model.I currently have groups->roles-> permissions mapping in global policy file as below:

```
[groups]
mapr = admin_role
analysts = analysts_role
reporters = reporters_role,globalreader_role
managers = managers_role

[roles]
admin_role = server=mydbserver
analysts_role = server=mydbserver->db=db1
reporters_role = server=mydbserver->db=db2
managers_role = server=mydbserver->db=*
globalreader_role = server=mydbserver->db=*->table=*->action=select
```

I want to switch to database model to load the above policies instead of file based model.How can we prepopulate the following sentry_store database tables to achieve the authorization policy?
I don't see any examples anywhere.

Tables in Sentry_Store database:

```
SENTRY_DB_PRIVILEGE          
SENTRY_GM_PRIVILEGE          
SENTRY_GROUP                 
SENTRY_ROLE                  
SENTRY_ROLE_DB_PRIVILEGE_MAP 
SENTRY_ROLE_GM_PRIVILEGE_MAP 
SENTRY_ROLE_GROUP_MAP        
SENTRY_VERSION
```

Answer (score 0):

Since 1.4.0, Sentry can import configuration from a policy file using the config-tool. You just need to set HIVE_HOME to the path of your Hive installation first.

Usage example:

```
export HIVE_HOME=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hive
sentry --command config-tool --import -i hdfs://namenode:8020/user/hive/sentry/sentry-provider.ini
```

This tool is documented in [ASF JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SENTRY-199?jql=project%20%3D%20SENTRY%20AND%20text%20~%20%22migrate%20policy%20file%22)